# SQL: write nested query in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery

My table has folloiwng columns:

AccountKey
ProductGroup
ProductVersion

I want to list the distinct AccountKey that have ProductGroup=A with ProductVersion=13 and without ProductGroup=A with ProductVersion =19.

Please share the sql code.

Thanks very much!

Sorry I think i am not clear on the question above:
The table is storing the productgroup and product version each accountkey has bought. So one accountkey could have bought multiple products in the same productGroup but with different ProductVersions.

I want to know what are the accountKey that have bought ProductGroup A version 13 but not 19.

e.g. if my table is like below
AccountKey ProductGroup  ProductVersion
123           A              13,
123           A              19,
456           B              10,
456           A              13,
789           B              19,

So the result i want is 456 only for the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountKey
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (ProductGroup = 'A' AND ProductVersion = 13) 
   OR (ProductGroup != 'A' AND ProductVersion = 19)
```

Comment: thank you all. i am trying to use this to solve a UI subquery/nested filter. It is hard to get the user to transform the business requirements to (ProductGroup != 'A' AND ProductVersion = 19) this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountKey 
FROM Table 
WHERE (ProductGroup = 'A' AND ProductVersion = 13) 
   OR (ProductGroup <> 'A' AND ProductVersion = 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountKey
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (ProductGroup = 'A' AND ProductVersion = 13) 
   AND NOT (ProductGroup = 'A' AND ProductVersion = 19)
```

...which will include ProductGroups other than 'A'.

Or do you want to limit results to only ProductGroup 'A'?